# How many session/connections the oracle 11G R2 Express Edition support?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I need to know if the 11G R2 XE has a limitation of session/connections.
Like in an office. Can I have 15 people using the same system, at the same time? He can handle or I'll lose performance or some other problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle XE (any version) has certain limitations when compared to Standard and/or Enterprise editions. As of 11g XE, they are listed in the Licensing Restrictions (here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW117), which include

- one CPU usage
- 1 GB RAM
- 11 GB of user data

but number of sessions/connections isn't limited.

As of performance: it depends on what those users do. Even if you have two users, one of which uses a lot of CPU, then another one will suffer. The same goes for available RAM. For "normal" processing, you should be OK. You know how it goes ... for price you pay ($0), it is just *great*. You can always upgrade to Standard Edition, but it will cost you (a lot of) money.

By the way, why wouldn't you install 18c XE which is available for both Windows and Linux? Is there any particular reason why you'd want to use 11g XE?

Comment: I'm considering to buy a software, and they use this version. I searched but I couldn't find nothing specific about that. I'll have to search the amount of cpu and ram that the software uses. but Thank you! so much for answering my question.